# Parsing currency value in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel-2010

Ok... I guess my brain has finally gone on vacation without me today.  I have extracted 2 fields from a website and I get this string

```
vData = "Amount Owed [EXTRACT]$125.00[EXTRACT]
```

`vData` was declared as an array (string).

I split `vData` on `[EXTRACT]` and I end up with 2 string variables like this:

```
varA = "Amount Owed"
varB = "$125.00"
```

To parse `varB`, I use

```
Dim varC as Currency
varC = val(varB)
```

I want to use `varC` in an `If` statement:

```
If Val(VarC) <> 0 Then
```

I was expecting `varC` to be 125 but when I look at `varC` is 0.  I can't figure out why `varC` = 0 and not 125.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CCur(varB)` instead of `Val(varB)`.  `CCur` converts to a `Currency` type, so knows about `$` and other things.

Explanation from the [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278896(v=office.14).aspx):

> ... when you use `CCur`, different decimal separators, different thousand separators, and various currency options are properly recognized depending on the locale setting of your computer.

`Val` is [only looking for straight numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296(v=office.14).aspx):

> The `Val` function stops reading the string at the first character it can't recognize as part of a number. Symbols and characters that are often considered parts of numeric values, such as dollar signs and commas, are not recognized.

Comment: @cxw..............Thanks for the information and suggestion.  I think I had used "val" in the past (without the $ sign) so it probably gave me the number I was looking for.